# Flatten 360 fisheye video

Tags: ffmpeg, virtual-reality, 360-degrees, 360-panorama

i recently bought a RICOH THETA S, for recording soccer games in 360 vr.
I would like to use ffmpeg to flatten my fisheye movie recorded with my cam, thats possible ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBgXz.jpg)

how can i do ?
Thanks !
Top

Comment: Can you explain "flatten"? Do you want to stitch the two halves together? This will create one equirectangular image which, in a way, makes it "flat." Also, are you recording a video or doing livestreaming?

Comment: Yes i want equirectangular ! im recording, and want to transform the mp4 file...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the Remap filter with FFmpeg.
Have a look here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter

From the webpage of the filter:

> This can be used to create 360 movies with equirectangular projection, for example to upload to youtube. Attached also for specific 360 camera's:
>
> - Ricoh Theta S camera: input files for resolution 1920x960(1080).

You should be able to write your own code to project fisheye lens image from the theta to some rectilinear image. But maybe equirectangular projection could also be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new filter in ffmpeg, called "v360".

This line converts from dual fisheye to equirectangular, assuming the FOV of the cameras is 190° (adjust per your needs):

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -vf v360=dfisheye:e:ih_fov=190:iv_fov=190:yaw=0 -y output_file
```

[image: dual fishey to equirectangular examples]

This line instead converts from a **single** fisheye image 235° wide and pointing toward the horizon, to equirectangular:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360=**dfisheye**:e:ih_fov=235:iv_fov=235 -y output.jpg
```

Parameters:

- -i: input_file
- -vf: filter_name=filter_parameters
- -y: overwrite output
- filename: output file

v360 filter:

- dfisheye: source projection: double fisheye
- e (or "equirectangular"): destination projection: equirectangular
- pitch: viewing direction in source fisheye picture; 0=horizon, 90=up, -90=down
- yaw: viewing direction in source fisheye: positive=right, negative = left, 180 = back
- ih_fov: input horizontal Field Of View
- iv_fov: input vertical Field of View

Note: I am not the guy in the picture, I found the pitcure around...